# Do eigenvectors of a Toeplitz matrix form an orthogonal set?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, toeplitz-matrices

It is true for a $2 \times 2$ Toeplitz matrix (put values $a$ and $b$ in the first row and $b$ and $a$ in the second and work out), but when I tried it for a $3 \times 3$, it turns out to be a bit difficult.

Any help or reference to my question is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: They can't. Take $v\not=0$ an eigenvector. Then $2v$ is also an eigenvector and it's not orthogonal to $v$.

Comment: However, if you take a set of linearly independant eigenvectors, it can work. You can prove that two eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal. But if one of the eigenspaces have dim > 2 then you could have two lineraly independant but not orthogonal eigenvectors. In fact, for a set of linearly independant vectors, the set is orthogonal $\iff$ each subset associated with a particular eigenvalue is orthogonal.

Comment: For a 2 by 2, I found eigenvalues $a+b$ and $a-b$ and eigenvectors <1,1> and <1,-1> respectively. And they work and they are orthogonal. But is it correct to assume that it only works for a 2 by 2 matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 8&0&0}$. Then $\det(xI-A)=x^3-8$ and $A$ has three distinct, simple eigenvalues. That is, $A$ has an eigenbasis and all its eigenspaces are one-dimensional. However, $A^TA-AA^T=\pmatrix{63&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&-63}\ne0$. Therefore $A$ is not normal, i.e. it has two different eigenspaces (corresponding to two different eigenvalues) that are not orthogonal to each other.

Comment: This is not a Toeplitz matrix.

Comment: Sorry, it is and so I have an idea about my conjecture now!